# How to dynamically extend a class ref in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, javascript-inheritance

I'd like to pass a class ref definition to a function. The function should then make the passed class ref extend another class. Heres an example. I would expect to see `console.log` output "Root constructor" but it does not because `InputClass` gets overriden with the `extends` line.

```
class Root {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Root constructor');
  }
}

function decorateClass(InputClass){
  class InnerClass {
    constructor(){

    }
  }

  // should extend InputClass but not override
  return class InputClass extends InnerClass{}
}

var ExtendedClass = decorateClass(Root);
var ec = new ExtendedClass();
// Should log 'Root constructor'
```

Comment: Classes are mostly just syntactic sugar for functions and prototypes. If you want to make changes dynamically, do it by manipulating the prototypes.

Comment: Here's a pretty similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599560/javascript-class-extend-on-condition/42599645#42599645

Answer (score 0):

Your code is extending the `InnerClass`, not the `InputClass` that you are passing to the function. The function argument is completely ignored.

I think you're looking for

```
function decorateClass(InputClass){
  class InnerClass extends InputClass {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    constructor(){
      super();
    }
  }

  return InnerClass;
}
```

Comment: no, unfortunately this is confusing, I essentially want the `super` of `InputClass` to propagate to `InnerClass`

Comment: @kevzettler That's not really possible, there is no `super()` in `InputClass` so it won't propagate.

Comment: you're telling us even with extreme prototype manipulation that "its not really possible?" Just want to make sure before I stop pursuing

Comment: @kevzettler Yes. it is not possible if the "decorated" class did not already inherit from something (i.e. used `extends`). Your only choice is to create a new class then to overwrite the "decorated" class.